# Is setting values in inspector the same as setting default values in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very new to Unity, so this might be a dumb question, but is setting values in inspector the same as setting default values in code?

Example:

```
public string name; //then go to inspector and set it as "Bob".
```

or

```
public string name = "Bob";
```

So, to rephrase, will these actions above achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> will these actions above achieve the same effect?

**Yes**, they will both accomplish the-same thing. They will both initialize the `name` variable with the "Bob" value once you click the "Play" button.

It's highly recommended that you **don't** set the default value from code if you make the field variable to be `public`. The reason for this is because you will run into a bug that will take you time to discover and fix.

For example, lets say you had this:

```
public string name = "Bob";
```

Then you go to the Editor to let it compile. Later on, you went back to the code and changed it to *"Jake"*:

```
public string name = "Jake";
```

While programming, you would still think that the value is now "Jake" and expecting your code to do something based on "Jake" value. This will fail since `name` is still "Bob". The latest value of name variable is shown in the Editor until the `name` variable renamed or the script/component that holds the `name` variable is reset:

[image]

This is a time waster issue and yes, some people still go through it. If you want to make the variable `public` but don't want to assign it from the Editor, use the [`[HideInInspector]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HideInInspector.html) attribute to hide it.

```
[HideInInspector]
public string name = "Bob";
```

This will make sure you won't mistakenly change it in the Editor and cause issues while allowing your variable to be accessed from other scripts.

---

This only applies where the variable is declared. You can change the variable in function or property later on and the changes should take effect without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly: as soon as you attach your script to an object for the first time, and you have global variables initialized into its code, Unity sets the corresponding Inspector's values with those.

But, once a variable is set in the Inspector, you can change that only by the Inspector itself, and no more by code.

Obviously, this just applies for types that do not depend by assets (primitives, Vector2, Vector3, etc...). In case of Prefabs, Materials, etc... the only way is by always passing from the Inspector, of course.

In conclusion: never rely on code initialization! Always make sure that by Inspector they are set correctly as you want.